# visual development, tool like MS Access for web/Mobile

Tags: ms-access, web-applications, mobile

Is there a tool, similar to MS Access but for Web. Which will allow users to create line-of-business applications and report-applications in a visual environment, but also is backed with a scripting/programming environment?

Note: 
In general, I am not fan of MS Access, but in many situation it showed as very efficient way to let the user manipulate data, screens and reports by them self and just help them with the most difficult parts, which required programming.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for something similar to MS Access for a while.
I have used access for a long time to build data acquisition tools in a similar way to how lab-view works. I have found the strength of access are the form designer, the query designer, and its ability to work with MSSQL in .adp mode. Also it's ability to use other components from MS office and other com object model based libraries etc. The immediate mode allows for very rapid testing of the vba code. I can not work as productively in visual studio VB.net or any IDE I have tried thus far. However I am not a computer science expert so I hope someone has more knowledge than I do about this.

So far the closest tools I have seen are Alpha 5 v11 and RAD Studio X3 Delphi.
I looked at Limnor Studio VS, MS Light-switch. I tried Python but couldn't find a GUI work as well as in Access. Most of the uses I have are in the area of controlling devices by LAN or GPIB and pulling data off of them for later plotting or other analysis.

I would be very interested to hear of more possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at [Morfik](http://morfik.com/) (http://morfik.com/).

If you know your way around in Access, you'll pick up Morfik in no-time.

You can program your stuff in Java, C#, BASIC and Object Pascal.
It'll be easy to deploy it as a website, and the UI is really slick.

There are many videos online that demonstrate how it works.

Comment: Oh, I see that Morfik is free nowadays. sweet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [m-Power](http://www.mrc-productivity.com/). I wouldn't really compare it with MS Access, but it will let users create line-of-business applications and report-applications in a visual environment.